# How to control the OMNeT++ Simulation using Python script / Python code

Tags: python, api, omnet++

I want to control the simulation process like **run-pause-resume-restart(mainly)**, import data, export data etc. just using the python script. Is it possible ? If it is possible then please give some direction or resources to proceed.

I am just starting in this field.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting/importing result data is available in OMNeT++ 6.0. Take a look at the `samples/results` folder for examples and the Manual's Result Recording and Analysis chapter.

Additional python integration (like writing behavior in Python or controlling the simulation) is planned for the upcoming 7.0 version. You may try the current `master` branch from the omnetpp github repo. The functionality was already merged into the master branch.

Comment: Where can I get the information about the new functionality in the current master branch?? and How to use that functionality ?

Comment: You have to browse the commit history. Also some features has samples that you can explore (like in case of python functionality, we enhanced the routing example with python code). Apart from that, you have to wait until the features stabilize and we start to add documentation to the manual.